# Can any body explain this code from Hello Android book

Tags: android

I cannot understand this code in page number 68-69  in Hello Android book. Some methods used in the code are new to me. Can anybody elaborate and explain the code.

```
private static final String TAG = "Sudoku" ;
private void openNewGameDialog() {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
      .setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
      .setItems(R.array.difficulty, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface,int i) {
           startGame(i);
          }
})
.show();
}
private void startGame(int i) {
Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " + i);
// Start game here...
}
```

Comment: How about you tell us what you don't understand?

Comment: which object does 'this' here refer, is it the same activity? and about OnClickListener() function.

Comment: 'this' refers to an instance of a class the openNewGameDialog() method belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it does is when you call openNewGameDialog() it will create an alertdialog with an assigned title and list of options from a resource file ("R.array.difficulty" is an integer value ultimately pointing to a string-array declared in the file /res/values/arrays.xml). An AlertDialog is a simple to create way of getting input from the user. It can also be used for output, but many prefer Toast for that task. The 
.show() at the end of it brings the dialog to the foreground.

When the items are added in that call they are assigned an onClick listener which when an item is clicked it sends the index of that item to startGame. In that function it only sends a message including the index to the logcat debug system.